# segmentation fault in recursion linkedlist sum c++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

Here is my part code for sum by using recursion, but I got segmentation fault. It looks like the problem was how to make an exit; however, I can't figure it out.

```
int LinkedList::sumR()
{
    int _sumR(Node* node);
}

int LinkedList::_sumR(Node* node)
{
    Node* curr = head;
    if(!curr)
        return 0;
        
    else
        return curr->value + _sumR(curr->next);
}
```

private in class

```
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node(int value) : value(value), next(nullptr) {}
        Node(int value, Node* next) : value(value), next(next) {}

        int value;
        Node* next;
    };

    int _sumR(Node* node);
    Node* head;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the first line of your `_sumR()` to this -

```
Node* curr = node;
```

I guess `head` is a member variable which points to the head of the list. If in every iteration you set `curr` to `head`, then the sum will be value of head added infinite times (or until the program crashes).

Another problem is you are not calling `_sumR()` from `sumR()` but just redefining it.

So the correct code will be -

```
int LinkedList::sumR()
{
    return _sumR(head);
}

int LinkedList::_sumR(Node* node)
{
    Node* curr = node;

    if(!curr)
        return 0;
    else
        return curr->value + _sumR(curr->next);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got another way that was change _sumR (Node* node) to _sumR(Node* currHead). I cannot understand how I can change the reference of function?

Comment: Does changing _sumR (Node* node) to _sumR(Node* currHead) fixes the issue?